# Why doesn't EditText.setRawInputType work anymore for Android 13?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have found that setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER) doesn't change the keyboard to numeric view.

setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER) remains available, but that means it's no longer possible to insert a number like this 4.44E+10 and add a thousands separator due to the removal of any non-digit characters.

Is this a bug or just an innovative solution from Google?

Comment: But it seems to work now, at least on Samsung devices, so my question is not relevant!